# EF core: cross context timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql-server, timestamp, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I have a test project for EF Core where I am testing a MySql and a Sql server contexts. I have the following property:

```
[Timestamp]
public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
```

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency,

> For SQL Server, timestamp is usually used on a byte[] property, which will be setup as a ROWVERSION column in the database

However, for MySql I need to use DataTime or it gives an error when attempting to save a new record. In SQL server, if I migrate with `DateTime`, it doesn't assign Timestamp as default. That is, each time I create a new record it shows an error saying the `CreatedOn` column can't be null.

I am using the `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` for MySql. The reason I am trying multiple contexts is to simulate situations such as changing databases in the middle of development.

Is there a way to set something a timestamp that is common in both? If not a normal property, a shadow property will do too.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue, did you figure it out ?

Comment: no... I just use DateTime with default value

Comment: Here is an issue on github [link](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/605) and stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823809/how-to-create-createdon-and-updatedon-using-ef-core-2-1-and-pomelo)