# How to prevent a column update in EF Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

I upgraded from .Net Core 2.2 to 3.1 and this functionality has been deprecated

```
modelBuilder
.Entity<Order>()
.Property(e => e.CreationTime)
.ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
.Metadata.IsStoreGeneratedAlways = true;
```

I need EF to do the Insert but block the update.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the obsoleted property [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v2.2.8/src/EFCore/Metadata/Internal/Property.cs#L444):

```
public virtual bool IsStoreGeneratedAlways
{
    get => AfterSaveBehavior == PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore || BeforeSaveBehavior == PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
    set
    {
        if (value)
        {
            BeforeSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
            AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
        }
        else
        {
            BeforeSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Save;
            AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Save;
        }
    }
}
```

the equivalent code should set `BeforeSaveBehavior` and `AfterSaveBehavior` to `Ignore`.

Also since `BeforeSaveBehavior` and `AfterSaveBehavior` properties have been replaced with `Get` / `Set` method pairs, it would require introducing a temporary variable to hold the property metadata.

Something like this:

```
var creationTime = modelBuilder
    .Entity<Order>()
    .Property(e => e.CreationTime)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
    .Metadata;
creationTime.SetBeforeSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
creationTime.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iproperty.aftersavebehavior?view=efcore-2.2), IsStoreGeneratedAlways become obsolete from 3.1.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata Assembly:
>
> If Throw, then an exception will be thrown if a new value is assigned
>   to this property after the entity exists in the database.
>
> If Ignore, then any modification to the property value of an entity
>   that already exists in the database will be ignored.

You should try something like this:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Order>()
    .Property(e =>.CreationTime).Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
```