# DbContext.SaveChanges overrides behaves unexpected

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have an EFCore, .NET5 application. Most of my models use a base class:

```cs
public class BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(512), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(8192)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Required]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = "Admin";
    
    [Required]
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    
    [Required]
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; } = "Admin";
}
```

I also have a configuration file:

```cs
public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
{
    builder.Property(b => b.CreatedOn).HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()").ValueGeneratedNever();
    builder.Property(b => b.CreatedBy).HasDefaultValue("External").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    builder.Property(b => b.UpdatedOn).HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");
    builder.Property(b => b.UpdatedBy).HasDefaultValue("External");
}
```

I override the `SaveChangesAsync()` method to try to add and update the Created and Updated properties automatically:

```cs
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new())
{
    var entries = ChangeTracker
        .Entries()
        .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseModel &&
                    e.State is EntityState.Added or EntityState.Modified);

    foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
    {
        if (entityEntry.State is EntityState.Detached or EntityState.Unchanged) continue;

        ((BaseModel)entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        ((BaseModel) entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedBy = _userId;

        if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            ((BaseModel)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            ((BaseModel) entityEntry.Entity).CreatedBy = _userId;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

I want to accomplish that the `CreatedOn` and `CreatedBy` are only updated on insert. But they are also updated on update.

This looks fine:

```sql
INSERT INTO [Organization] ([CreatedBy], [CreatedOn], [Description], [Name], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedOn], [UserProfileId])
```

This doesn't:

```sql
UPDATE [Organization] SET [CreatedBy] = @p0, [CreatedOn] = @p1, [Description] = @p2, [Name] = @p5, [UpdatedBy] = @p6, [UpdatedOn] = @p7, [UserProfileId] = @p8
```

I would have expected an update statement without `CreatedBy` and `CreatedOn`:

```sql
UPDATE [Organization] SET [Description] = @p2, [Name] = @p5, [UpdatedBy] = @p6, [UpdatedOn] = @p7, [UserProfileId] = @p8
```

Now, these properties get overwritten by the default values.

I've looked at numerous examples and have been trying different options all day, but I don't see what I do wrong. Please advice.

I also have an issue with getting the UserProfileId, but I'll create a new question for that.

Comment: [How to prevent a column update in EF Core 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977743/how-to-prevent-a-column-update-in-ef-core-3-1/59978378#59978378)

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Your suggestion helped me in finding a workable solution. I posted my solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of @IvanStoev I finally found a working solution.

I added

```cs
if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)
{
    entityEntry.Property("CreatedOn").IsModified = false;
    entityEntry.Property("CreatedBy").IsModified = false;
}
```

to my `SaveChangesAsync()` and removed the `ValueGenerated*` properties in my configuration and removed the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attributes in my base model.