# How to inject a service in my DbContext class and have host.MigrateDatabase() still working

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I've got a working EFCore, .NET5, Blazor WASM application.
I call `await host.MigrateDatabase();` in my `Program.Main()` to have my database always up-to-date.

```cs
public static async Task<IHost> MigrateDatabase(this IHost host)
{
    using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
    try
    {
        // Get the needed context factory using DI:
        var contextFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>>();
        // Create the context from the factory:
        await using var context = contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        // Migrate the database:
        await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    return host;
}
```

In my `AppDbContext` I've overridden `SaveChangesAsync()` to add and update `CreatedOn` en `UpdatedOn`.
I mentioned this in [DbContext.SaveChanges overrides behaves unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67484802/dbcontext-savechanges-overrides-behaves-unexpected) before.
I also want to fill `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy` with the userId.

I have an `IdentityOptions` class to hold the user data:

```cs
public class IdentityOptions
{
    public string UserId => User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value; 
    public ClaimsPrincipal User { get; set; }
}
```

I've registered this class in StartUp like this:

```cs
services.AddScoped(sp =>
{
    var context = sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext;
    var identityOptions = new IdentityOptions();

    if (context?.User.Identity != null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        identityOptions.User = context.User;
    }
    return identityOptions;
});
```

I inject this `IdentityOptions` class into several other services, without any problem.
But when I inject it in my `AppDbContext`:

```cs
public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, IdentityOptions identityOptions)
    : base(options)
{
    ...
}
```

I get an error in `MigrateDatabase()`:
`"Cannot resolve scoped service 'IdentityOptions' from root provider."`

I've been trying numerous options I found googling but can't find a solution that works for me.
Please advice.

**Update**:

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection"),
            b => b.MigrationsAssembly("DataAccess"))
#if DEBUG
        .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, new [] {RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted})
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
#endif
);
```

Comment: How are you registering the db context factory? `AddDbContextFactory`? Lifetime? (default is Singleton).

Comment: Thanks Ivan for your reply. I've updated my question. I use `AddDbContextFactory`

Comment: Have you tried to pass different lifetime, like `Scoped` (the last optional parameter of `AddDbContextFactory`)? I'm not a specialist with DI, but injecting scoped into singleton sounds problematic (logically). Let me know if that helps, otherwise you might need your own `IDbContextFactory<>` implementation. But let see this first.

Comment: Yes Ivan. Adding `lifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped` solved my problem. Can you post it as an answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped mate. But as I said, I'm far from DI, so please feel free to post and accept a self answer (for future readers), and I'll be happy to UV it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the great help of @IvanStoev (again), I found the answer.
Adding `lifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped` to `AddDbContextFactory` in `Startup` solved my problem.
Now I can use my IdentityOptions class in `SaveChanges` and automatically update my `Created*` and `Updated*` properties.